# how do i place a text upperright side of the image?

Tags: css

I am trying to make something like this using only CSS.
[image]

This is how it came out.

[image]

and this is my code.

```
<div class="info_1"><img src="images/xe_icon_2.png"><span>Powered by XE</span></div>
```

Now, I did give some css styling.

```
.info_1 {
   display: inline;
   clear:right;
}

.info_1 span{
   font-size: 20px;
   line-height: 100px;
}
```

what do i have to make a text appear on the upper right side of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting it before the image:

```
<div class="info_1">
    <span>Powered by XE</span>
    <img src="images/xe_icon_2.png">
</div>
```

and modifying the CSS a bit (you won't need that line height).

Or, you can keep the current markup, and make that span absolutely positioned and then fine-tune its position using `top` and `right` CSS rules.

---

Here's an example:

```css
#ctn {
  width: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px #aaa;
}
.info_1 {
  display: inline;
  clear: right;
}
.info_1 span {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
.info_1 img {
  margin: 20px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ctn">
  <div class="info_1">
    <span>Powered by XE</span>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE

```css
#main {
  width: 600px;
  background: #eee;
}
#ctn {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #999;
}
.info_1 span {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 10px;
}
.info_1 img {
  margin: 20px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="ctn">
    <div class="info_1">
      <span>Powered by XE</span>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh. so you gave the upper layer relative value to make the .info_1 span not go out of the .info_1 div  itself? i didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Yes, relatively positioned parent serves to position its absolutely positioned child so that you know that top/bottom/left/right values are in relation to the parent. I added that because I didn't know what the rest of your code looks like.

Comment: nice. but for some reason, it won't let me stretch far beyond what you wrote (300px) say, if i give #ctn 1000px width and make the span text go with right: 100px or something, it messes up with the alignment and go totally someplace else.

Comment: excuse me. i thought i increased the left value not right value. lol it works perfectly. thanks.

Comment: Something else is causing the misalignment - I've just added a 1000px / 710px right offset example. Yeah, the right offset is the number of pixels from the right edge of the relative element. You can also use left (the width of that image plus a few more pixels). You're welcome.

Comment: can i ask you one more question if you don't mind? I need to place the whole image and the text to be centered, but text-align:center and padding left and right auto don't work. is there a better way for this?

Comment: Put the text and the image inside a small container (that is not wider than the content), and then you can use `width: 300px; margin: auto;` to make it centered inside its parent element. I've updated my second example to show you what I mean.

Comment: it makes visually a lot of sense for someone like me. thanks for the snippets. i was going to ask another question, but since i can't ask another question in 90 minutes, i'd rather make it here. i copied and pasted the whole html above and make it 2 of those in HTML. but it won't be put side by side even if i give the #ctn display:inline. could you help me out?

Comment: Think of `#ctn` as a small centered container, if you still want element beside it, you can set it to inline-block instead. If you need more accuracy, feel free to add another element inside #ctn which will hold the span and the image (it's probably too much, but I have no idea about your structure). Thus my code was just to show you some ideas, not to be copy/pasted.